Why should the operands for UNION be SELECT statements and not tables?
In SQL, given tables T and S that have the same schema, say,
CREATE TABLE "T" ("ID" INTEGER, "Salary" REAL);
CREATE TABLE "S" ("ID" INTEGER, "Salary" REAL);

we can union the two relations with the command
(SELECT * FROM "S") UNION (SELECT * FROM "T");

but the following command gives an error:
"S" UNION "T";

Error message in SQLite: near "UNION": syntax error
Error message in SQL Server: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Why can't we use the latter command? Algebraically speaking, the union operator is defined to take two table operands and output another table as a result. So "S" UNION "T" must work. This is analogous to how the selection and projection operators take a table operand, and output another table.
I understand that while the output of a SELECT statement should algebraically be a table, it is in practice a "virtual table". My understanding from C. J. Date's An Introduction to Database Systems (8th Ed) is that tables like S and T above are "base relvars/relations" whereas virtual tables like (SELECT * FROM "S") and (SELECT * FROM "T") are "derived relations"; and that both (base and derived) are considered tables. So why don't they act the same when UNION operates on them?
Interestingly, after we give the names view1 and view2 to the outputs of (SELECT * FROM "S") and (SELECT * FROM "T") respectively to create views,
CREATE VIEW "view1" AS SELECT * FROM "S";
CREATE VIEW "view2" AS SELECT * FROM "T";

we will again get errors if we feed the views to UNION as operands:
"view1" UNION "view2";

Error message in SQLite: near "UNION": syntax error
Error message in SQL Server: Incorrect syntax near 'view1'.
What's happening? Why must the operands necessarily be SELECT statements?

UNION is an SQL keyword, that is similar to, but not the same as, the set theory union operator ∪.

Because that's the way the language was defined. (And SQL is a badly designed language.) This is a question about (programming language) history, not practical prgramming. Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?

While relational databases are built on top of relational algebra, they are not the same, especially actual implementations. Some versions of some RDBMS even don't conform to SQL standard (they are actually not required to fully support it to claim compatibility, some features are optional).
Anyway, SQL standard defines UNION operator the way you'd expect:
<non-join query expression> ::=
                <non-join query term>
              | <query expression> UNION  [ ALL ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>

if we unfold everything:

<query term> ::= <non-join query term>
<non-join query term> ::= <non-join query primary>
<non-join query primary> ::= <simple table>
<simple table> ::= <explicit table>
<explicit table> ::= TABLE <table name>


The <explicit table> TABLE <table name> is equivalent to the <query expression> ( SELECT * FROM <table name> )

so, according to the standard you should be able to use syntax like:
TABLE T UNION TABLE S
but actual implementation of SQL language is up to RDBMS developers, I don't know any to support explicit table statements like this, btw, the same for UNION JOIN, so answer to your question Why should the operands for UNION be SELECT statements and not tables? - because developers decided not to follow standard.

"defines UNION operator the way you'd expect" contradicts "you should be able to use syntax like:TABLE T UNION TABLE S".

@philipxy when we unfold everything, we can say that sql standard defines union (one of the variant of it) as  <explicit table> UNION <explicit table> - this is what OP expected to work

No they expect T UNION S to work. An  is not a bare table name.

@philipxy OP wants to use table names without select statement, assumed that syntax to be T UNION S, my point is that according to standard - it is possible (use table names without select), with slightly different syntax, but in practice even that does not work

@IłyaBursov So the output of a SELECT statement is, according to the standard, an explicit table. In contrast, calling a table by its table name doesn't return an explicit table. What does it return?

@Ardy  is a certain kind of table-valued expression in the grammar that is the token TABLE followed by a  expression. A  is a base table name. The bulleted lines with ::= are describing the grammar.

@Ardy select statement is <query expression> in grammar, and <explicit table> is equivalent to <query expression> which means that you should be able to use TABLE name instead of SELECT *.. according standard, but in reality...


have the same schema

If you have two base tables with identical schema, you should ask why isn't that one table? (Possibly with an extra column identifying which real-life scenario is giving rise to the row being in the table.)
Consider this more usual style of query:
SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 2;

≡

SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 1 OR X = 2;

≡

SELECT * FROM T WHERE X IN (1, 2);

Usually a UNION is for OR'ing together the results from different selection conditions over the same base table -- hence the operands will naturally have the same schema.
